# How to solve “resource requires the request to be CORS enabled… resource has been blocked because the integrity cannot be enforced” error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, cors, subresource-integrity

I am using bootstrap icons in my project which gives me error

> Subresource Integrity: The resource
>   'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'
>   has an integrity attribute, but the resource requires the request to
>   be CORS enabled to check the integrity, and it is not. The resource
>   has been blocked because the integrity cannot be enforced.

Can any one help me to solve this issue and when we move to production the icon is not loaded.

So I am using below link for bootstrap icons

```
%link{:href => "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css", :integrity => "sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
```

Comment: `crossOrigin="anonymous"` (casing important!) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think you are missing `crossorigin="anonymous"`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

> When the request doesn't match Same Origin Policy the crossorigin
>   attribute MUST be present for the integrity of the file to be checked.
>   With an integrity set on an external origin and a missing crossorigin
>   the browser will choose to 'fail-open' which means it will load the
>   resource as if the integrity attribute was not set.

[Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-sri#crossorigin-attribute)

Comment: Note for React Server Rendering Users: You need to use camelCase for `crossOrigin`.

Comment: crossOrigin is also case sensitive if you load async via javascript. `<script type="text/javascript"> (function() { var css = document.createElement('link'); css.href = 'https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css'; css.rel = 'stylesheet'; css.type = 'text/css'; css.integrity = 'sha384-somehash'; css.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; console.log(css); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css); })(); </script>`

Answer (score 27):

I was trying to insert jQuery into a page via the Chrome DevTools Console, and I was getting this error. Here's the code I was using:

```
// Bad code
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
script.crossorigin = 'anonymous';
script.integrity = 'sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

The solution was to change `crossorigin` to `crossOrigin` (uppercase O for Origin):

```
// Good code
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js';
script.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
script.integrity = 'sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: This was exactly the solution I needed, perfect!

Comment: Woohooo... this fixed it instantly :D