# Hugo-themed webpage not rendering certain elements as expected (using Netlify)

Tags: html, css, hugo, blogdown, toml

#### Excuse

Just learning .toml and have a rudimentary understanding of CSS and html (not enough, I think, to know where to look for this issue).

#### Relevant Info

- I have been working off of the original Hugo theme ([theme 1](https://github.com/TrashBirdEcology/burnett.wtf/tree/master/themes/hugo-theme-hello-friend-ng)) and adapted version ([theme 2](https://github.com/TrashBirdEcology/burnett.wtf/tree/master/themes/hugo-theme-hello-friend-ng_jlb-edits)), each having similar results.
- I am deploying a [website](http://burnett.wtf) via [Netlify](https://app.netlify.com/sites/burnett-wtf/deploys). [Here is the source code](https://github.com/TrashBirdEcology/burnett.wtf/tree/master/).

#### Problem

When I render the site locally (using `blogdown::serve_site()`), the drop down menu and the theme brightness elements (upper RHS of [the webpages](https://burnett.wtf); Fig. 1, Fig. 2) **work as expected** (the menu responds, and the theme goes from dark to light; Fig. 3).

#### Question

Does anyone see any obvious errors in my source code *or* can you point me to the location in the source code which I might test?

#### Figures

[image]

Fig. 1: elements of interest (left, drop down menu; right, theme brightness). the drop down menu will appear if you reduce width of window.

---

[image]

Fig. 2: demonstration of theme change from bright (Fig. 1) to dark (here) and loss of the drop-down menu (3 horizontal bars; occurs when browser window width is increased).

---

[image]

Fig. 3: demonstration of the drop-down menu **working as expected**. screenshot taken on local website rendering.

Comment: Did you see that your site has 2 errors in the console when you try to load it?

Comment: not sure what you mean by load?

Comment: Open your website and bring up the developer tools. There's a section in the bottom called console which will display 2 errors. They are basically blocking your resources and that's probably why it's not working when you host it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got similar integrity alerts for GitHub. Can you point me to why it would throw these errors?

Comment: It looks like https://www.burnett.wtf/site.webmanifest cannot be found, that would be something for you to check. For the other issue maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323268/how-to-solve-has-an-integrity-attribute-issue-on-bootstrap-min-css

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking at post you referenced. I appreciate your time and help.